# "This book includes three chapters, which {discusses/discuss} on..."

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses

In the following sentence, should it be 'discuss' or 'discusses'?

> This book includes three chapters, which discusses on the examples of adaptation, evolution and survival, providing a further understanding of the three processes.

Comment: I discuss, you discuss, he/she/it discusses. And *three chapters discuss the examples*, never *discuss on*

Comment: @Kevin I'd consider 'discuss on' old-fashioned rather than never acceptable.

Comment: What would you guess? Can you explain why you are unsure?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've never heard it used (except possibly some VERY specific grammatical constructions), and [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discuss%2Cdiscuss+on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiscuss%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiscuss%20on%3B%2Cc0) shows *discuss on* wasn't used before about 1738, and has always been about 1,000 times less used than just plain *discuss*. Certainly, if you have to ask or refer to this question you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score -1):

The verb *discuss* must agree with *three chapters,* so it needs the plural form, *discuss.* If the book contains exactly three chapters:

> This book includes three chapters, which discuss the examples...
>   The three chapters in this book discuss...

If it contains more than three chapters, remove the comma:

> This book includes three chapters which discuss the examples...
>   This book includes three chapters that discuss the examples...
>   Three chapters in this book discuss...

Note, also, that we *discuss* something, or we have a *discussion on* something, but we don't *discuss <s>on</s>* something.